# Widget icon not updating

Tags: android, android-widget, icons

I've defined an upload_widget.png file for my app widget, and declared it as below in my AndroidManifest.xml. It worked fine when I first created it, but I've now made a change to the .png image files (in each of /drawable folders), synchronised the files in Android Studio, but the widget icon is not reflecting the new .png files when I re-test the app on my Galaxy S4. 
When I long-press on the screen (I'm using Nova Launcher) and select "add widget" I see the correct icon in the "Choose Widget" list, but when I select it I get a different icon on the launcher - i.e. the old icon. When I run the app in a Nexus 5 emulator I get the same problem.
Any ideas??

```
<receiver android:name=".UploadWidget" android:icon="@drawable/upload_widget" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
    </intent-filter>

    <meta-data
        android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
        android:resource="@xml/upload_widget_info" />
</receiver>
```

**UPDATE**

Here is upload_widget_info:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:minWidth="40dp" android:minHeight="40dp" android:updatePeriodMillis="86400000"
    android:previewImage="@drawable/example_appwidget_preview"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/upload_widget" android:resizeMode="horizontal|vertical"
    android:widgetCategory="home_screen|keyguard"
    android:initialKeyguardLayout="@layout/upload_widget"></appwidget-provider>
```

Comment: Can you post `xml/upload_widget_info` please?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct. This is a common problem on devices running Lollipop. To fix it, navigate through these steps : Settings -> Apps -> Google App -> Manage Space -> Clear Launcher Data. Your shortcuts on the homepage will disappear but the widget icon will be correct.

Source: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=81076&thanks=81076&ts=1417102714

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but the devices I was testing on were running KitKat, not Lollipop

Comment: This fixed the problem for me. It may be specific to Google Now Launcher, as I am also testing on KitKat.